# localhost kernel: appex: not cloning BAD SKB: head=xxx

Tags: linux, centos

My CentOS 7.6.1810(Core) always restart automatically.

in the `/var/log/messages` there are many logs:

[image]

> localhost kernel: appex: not cloning BAD SKB: head=fff....

Comment: Is appex a 3rd party network driver?

Comment: I am not sure what's it.

Comment: My question was rhetorical: yes it is. But I'm afraid if you don't know about it yourself, nobody will. I don't grasp if it's handling a network card or accelerating tcp somehow: [AppEx_LotServer_Product_Brief.pdf](http://www.appexnetworks.com/Assets/PDF/AppEx_LotServer_Product_Brief.pdf) or [lotServerQ&A.pdf](http://download.appexnetworks.com/downloadlsQA.jsp) . You should just be sure that if you recently upgraded your centos kernel, you did the same for appex because it appears to include a kernel module. I don't know this product but found these URLs on internet.